# Record online blackboard with playback

Tags: html, canvas, record, blackboard

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to record a blackboard type of application in the webbrowser. Where a tutor can record a video of the blackboard with audio.

I think the obvious answer here is to make a html5 canvas and capture it at intervals as images and combine these to a video. [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781602/capturing-html5-canvas-output-as-video-or-swf-or-png-sequence)

However this has several disadvantages. It is not easy to edit the video later on. Also videos would require a lot of storage space.

What are your ideas? How can I construct this recording and playback of a blackboard?

/Jake

Comment: I think you would probably be better off with using a stand alone program such as the excellent [Jing by Tech Smith](http://www.techsmith.com/jing)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project that records HTML5 canvas drawings and allows you to play them back later. There are no images, everything is stored in the Javascript/JSON. There is no audio, so I plan on adding a transcript feature along with it. If you want to follow along with my project, it is at http://github.com/eipark. The code is still very much raw and buggy, but I am actively developing it for a school project and hope to have at least the "video" recording portion done in the next week.