# Is it possible to save a frame in THREE.Js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to save animation frames in THREE.js and play them back? I'm not talking about a video file or anything, but the actual animation frames that are sent into `requestAnimationFrame(renderFunction)`.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools can debug canvas animation one frame at a time. Other than that you can dump frames to PNG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781602/capturing-html5-canvas-output-as-video-or-swf-or-png-sequence

Comment: There's also https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if I do, then answer is NO - three.js itself won't provide you with mechanism to remember data about animation and load them back. Mainly for the reason that you can put anything you into your renderFunction and you would also be the person responsible to store and reload any data that you need for animating your objects.

Maybe you could achieve something by saving and later restoring whole scene, but this would take a lot of system resources and also might not do what you expect it to do.

Try to explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a great THREE.js tutorial by Jerome Etienne](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/) showing how to save individual frames as image files.