# Allow video download from html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am building a small app that allows to add css3 filters like grayscale in a video and download it. The video won't be longer than 6 seconds. So, I am first loading the video in the canvas and then applying the filter that user demands. Now I want user to be able to download the filtered video. The `canvas.toDataURL()` is only meant for images. Is there any high level canvas api to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. I think this is something that should be done server-side. Either send the raw video to the server and tell it what filters were applied so you can re-create the effect on the server OR use the solution proposed here [capturing html5 canvas output as video or swf or png sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781602/capturing-html5-canvas-output-as-video-or-swf-or-png-sequence) (hint: it's also server side)