# HTML5 Canvas to downloadable Video

Tags: html, canvas

How can I make a screen recording of whatever is drawn on the canvas and then make it a downloadable video?

Relevant questions:

1. [Convert HTML5 Canvas Sequence to a Video File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235286/convert-html5-canvas-sequence-to-a-video-file)
2. [MediaStream Capture Canvas and Audio Simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302814/mediastream-capture-canvas-and-audio-simultaneously)
3. [capturing html5 canvas output as video or swf or png sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781602/capturing-html5-canvas-output-as-video-or-swf-or-png-sequence)

Comment: You said https://stackoverflow.com/a/39302994/19068 is "Relevant", but it appears to completely answer your question. What about it is lacking?

Comment: @Quentin The "downloadable" bit is missing from the question you linked. I am planning to answer this question myself (I've been dealing with this general problem and I have a minimal working solution) so I'll vote to reopen once I have the answer ready.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention downloading the result. The duplicate gets the result from a call to `createObjectURL` though, and the second duplicate I just added covers downloading the output of that call.

Comment: The "downloading" part is literally in the title, and also implied in the "export to video" phrase. I am well aware that if I combine all 3 of the relevant questions I posted I get a full solution, albeit with a lot of manual work trying to fit together all the different bits and pieces. This is why I took it upon myself to create a single question with a complete answer; to help others from having to look through many different questions to solve a single problem.

Answer (score -1):

Setup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <section id="capture">
            <div>
                <button id="pause">Pause</button>
                <button id="resume">Resume</button>
                <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                <button id="record">Record</button>
            </div>
            <ol>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const onLoad = () => {

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.style.border = "5px solid black";

    // paint background so it's not transparent
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();

    // paint black circle on-click
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);
```

#### Recorder:

Wrapper over MediaRecorder. Its `stop()` function returns a Promise which in turn resolves with an object URL from the data captured by the MediaRecorder. This object will then be downloaded via an `<a>` tag.

```js
class Recorder {

    static RECORDER_OPTIONS = { mimeType: "video/webm" }

    constructor(canvas, fps) {
        this.stream = canvas.captureStream(fps);
    }

    start() {
        this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(
            this.stream, Recorder.RECORDER_OPTIONS
        );
        this.recorder.start();
    }

    stop() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", e => {
                let blob = e.data;
                let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                resolve(url);
            });

            this.recorder.stop();
        });
    }

    pause() {
        this.recorder.pause();
    }

    resume() {
        this.recorder.resume();
    }
}
```

#### Callback Functions for Buttons

These forward the calls to a Recorder. The `_stop_recording()` function takes the URL object and creates an `<a>` tag with it as its `href` attribute. The `download` attribute of the `<a>` tag is set to the desirable filename. Finally, it is appended to a list where the user can click it to download the file.

```js
let capture_count = 0;

let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const _recorder = new Recorder(canvas, 60);

const _start_recording = () => {
    _recorder.start();
}

const _stop_recording = () => {
    _recorder.stop()
        .then(url => {
            let ol = document.querySelector("section#capture>ol");
            let li = document.createElement("li");

            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute("href", url);
            let filename = `capture-${capture_count}`;
            a.textContent = filename;
            a.setAttribute("download", `capture-${filename}.webm`);

            li.appendChild(a);
            ol.appendChild(li);
            
            capture_count++;
        });
}

const _pause_recording = () => {
    _recorder.pause();
}

const _resume_recording = () => {
    _recorder.resume();
}

document.querySelector("#pause").addEventListener("click", _pause_recording);
document.querySelector("#resume").addEventListener("click", _resume_recording);
document.querySelector("#stop").addEventListener("click", _stop_recording);
document.querySelector("#record").addEventListener("click", _start_recording);
```

#### Better UI

There are two problems with the UI:

1. The user does not know the current state of the recording
2. Every button is clickable leading to undefined situations (e.g. pausing a recording which hasn't started).

To solve these issues, store the current state of the recording and use it to change the UI accordingly.

```js
const State = {
    STOPPED: "STOPPED",
    RECORDING: "RECORDING",
    PAUSED: "PAUSED",
}

const goto_state = (() => {

    let pause_btn = document.querySelector("button#pause");
    let resume_btn = document.querySelector("button#resume");
    let stop_btn = document.querySelector("button#stop");
    let record_btn = document.querySelector("button#record");

    const set_buttons = (pause, resume, stop, record) => {
        pause_btn.disabled = !pause;
        resume_btn.disabled = !resume;
        stop_btn.disabled = !stop;
        record_btn.disabled = !record;
    }

    let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

    const set_border = (color) => {
        canvas.style.border = `5px solid ${color}`;
    }

    return (state) => {
        switch (state) {
            case State.STOPPED:
                set_buttons(false, false, false, true);
                set_border("black");
                break;
            case State.RECORDING:
                set_buttons(true, false, true, false);
                set_border("red");
                break;
            case State.PAUSED:
                set_buttons(false, true, true, false);
                set_border("orange");
                break;
        }
    }
})();
```

All that is left now, is for the `_xxx_recording()` functions to call `goto_state()` with the appropriate state.

#### Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="test.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <section id="capture">
            <div>
                <button id="pause">Pause</button>
                <button id="resume">Resume</button>
                <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                <button id="record">Record</button>
            </div>
            <ol>
            </ol>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const onLoad = () => {

    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.style.border = "5px solid black";

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0, 50, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fill();
    
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", onLoad);

class Recorder {

    static RECORDER_OPTIONS = { mimeType: "video/webm", }

    constructor(canvas, fps) {
        this.stream = canvas.captureStream(fps);
    }

    start() {
        this.recorder = new MediaRecorder(
            this.stream, Recorder.RECORDER_OPTIONS
        );
        this.recorder.start();
    }

    stop() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", e => {
                let blob = e.data;
                let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                resolve(url);
            });

            this.recorder.stop();
        });
    }

    pause() {
        this.recorder.pause();
    }

    resume() {
        this.recorder.resume();
    }
}
const State = {
    STOPPED: "STOPPED",
    RECORDING: "RECORDING",
    PAUSED: "PAUSED",
}

const goto_state = (() => {

    let pause_btn = document.querySelector("button#pause");
    let resume_btn = document.querySelector("button#resume");
    let stop_btn = document.querySelector("button#stop");
    let record_btn = document.querySelector("button#record");

    const set_buttons = (pause, resume, stop, record) => {
        pause_btn.disabled = !pause;
        resume_btn.disabled = !resume;
        stop_btn.disabled = !stop;
        record_btn.disabled = !record;
    }

    let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

    const set_border = (color) => {
        canvas.style.border = `5px solid ${color}`;
    }

    return (state) => {
        switch (state) {
            case State.STOPPED:
                set_buttons(false, false, false, true);
                set_border("black");
                break;
            case State.RECORDING:
                set_buttons(true, false, true, false);
                set_border("red");
                break;
            case State.PAUSED:
                set_buttons(false, true, true, false);
                set_border("orange");
                break;
        }
    }
})();

let capture_count = 0;

let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const _recorder = new Recorder(canvas, 60);

const _start_recording = () => {
    _recorder.start();
    goto_state(State.RECORDING);
}

const _stop_recording = () => {
    _recorder.stop()
        .then(url => {
            let ol = document.querySelector("section#capture>ol");
            let li = document.createElement("li");

            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute("href", url);
            let filename = `capture-${capture_count}`;
            a.textContent = filename;
            a.setAttribute("download", `capture-${filename}.webm`);

            li.appendChild(a);
            ol.appendChild(li);
            
            capture_count++;
            goto_state(State.STOPPED);
        });
}

const _pause_recording = () => {
    _recorder.pause();
    goto_state(State.PAUSED);
}

const _resume_recording = () => {
    _recorder.resume();
    goto_state(State.RECORDING);
}

document.querySelector("#pause").addEventListener("click", _pause_recording);
document.querySelector("#resume").addEventListener("click", _resume_recording);
document.querySelector("#stop").addEventListener("click", _stop_recording);
document.querySelector("#record").addEventListener("click", _start_recording);
```

Relevant MDN documentation:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a